# Is there a command called "on" to execute commands on remote computers?

Tags: shell-script, rhel, remote

I've come across a bash script which finds out memory, CPU usage etc. on remote machines. To do that it uses a technique like this:

```
i=RemoteServerName

TOTALMEM=`on $i cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' `
```

I have searched in internet and it looks like all are using ssh username@RemoteServerName to achieve this. I am not understanding how this "on" works. The script works fine, but when I execute the command outside the script, it says: -bash: on: command not found..

I have searched in man pages, nothing found. Also, I have searched for any aliases that "on" stands for using command "type on". But nothing is found. Please help me understanding how this "on" works to execute commands on remote machines. I don't think there's a command called "on". Please help.

Both the local and remote machines are Redhat 6.2

Comment: It may be local, or it may be defined by the site you got the script from.

Comment: Can you edit the script to add the `type on` just before the TOTALMEM line? In addition to it being a command or an alias it might be a shell function, defined in either this script or in a file which is sourced by this script.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply. My bad, it was my mistake not to search outside root's environment. I have added the update as an edit to the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: @roaima sure. Have corrected my mistake and posted my solution as an answer. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

I found it. All I did initially was searching everywhere in my (root's) environment for an alias called "on". But then I checked how this script is being used in the server. It is used to generate hourly resource utilization of many other remote servers. So it should be a part of crontab. Yes, there we got it! This script is part of a user specific crontab of another user (non root).

There were these lines in the script:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

That user's ~/bin has the executable "on" which has all the required code to convert `on $i` to `ssh servername`.

If you are wondering why this extra step instead of directly using `ssh servername`, here is the explanation. The code format that I showed above was just a format and in the actual script it is used to generate reports of many servers (which are grouped into several groups) like below:

```
for i in $GROUP1 $GROUP2 $GROUP3
do 
   TOTALMEM=`on $i cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' `
   #other report generation and formatting code here
done
```

GROUP1, GROUP2 etc. are lists containing hostnames of similar servers.

Servers belonging to one group have common credentials for logging in. File "on" contains all the required code to form the command `ssh username@servername` based on their group, using case statement.